# Web API - An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Can't figure this one out. Thoughts?

[Controller]

```
await _imageRepo.Resize(name, width, height, queryParams, (image) =>
{
    response = createResponse(image);
});
```

[Repository]

```
public async Task Resize(string name, string width, string height, ImageOptions options, Action<Images> callback)
{
    var actionName = "resized";
    var newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(width);
    var newHeight = string.IsNullOrEmpty(height) ? newWidth : Convert.ToInt32(height);
    var resizedName = ApplyOptionName(string.Format("{0}-{3}-{1}x{2}", name, newWidth, newHeight, actionName), options);

    await Get(resizedName, null, async (previousImage) =>
    {
        if (previousImage != null)
        {
            callback(previousImage);
            return;
        }

        await Get(name, null, image =>
        {
            if (image == null)
            {
                callback(null);
                return;
            }

            using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory())
            {
                imageFactory.Load(image.ToStream());

                imageFactory.Resize(new ResizeLayer(new Size(newWidth, newHeight), ResizeMode.Max, AnchorPosition.Left));

                ProcessImageOptions(imageFactory, options);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    imageFactory.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                    var newImage = Create(new Images(ms) { Name = resizedName });

                    callback(newImage);
                }
            }

        });

    });

}
```

[Exception]

```
[InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]
```

All these callbacks don't sit well in my stomach but why am I getting this error?

Comment: I would have your repo return the image, then construct the response. (get rid of the callback parameter)

Comment: I suspect `Get`'s callback is an `Action`, which would force the `async` lambda to be `async void`, causing this issue. The best solution is to get rid of the callbacks altogether IMO, but you could also change them to `Func<..., Task>` and `await` them.

Answer (score 0):

While callbacks aren't great. We decided to continue using that pattern. Which meant figuring out how to  make those lambda's return tasks.

Which is pretty easy.

As Stephen Cleary writes "change them to Func<..., Task>...".

So here was the final implementation.

```
public async Task Resize(string name, string width, string height, ImageOptions options, Func<Images, Task> callback)
{
    var actionName = "resized";
    var newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(width);
    var newHeight = string.IsNullOrEmpty(height) ? newWidth : Convert.ToInt32(height);
    var resizedName = ApplyOptionName(string.Format("{0}-{3}-{1}x{2}", name, newWidth, newHeight, actionName), options);

    await Get(resizedName, null, async (previousImage) =>
    {
        Images resizedImage = null;

        if (previousImage != null)
        {
            resizedImage = previousImage;
        }
        else
        {
            await Get(name, null, async (image) =>
            {
                if (image == null)
                {
                    resizedImage = null;
                    return;
                }

                using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory())
                {
                    imageFactory.Load(image.ToStream());

                    imageFactory.Resize(new ResizeLayer(new Size(newWidth, newHeight), ResizeMode.Max, AnchorPosition.Left));

                    ProcessImageOptions(imageFactory, options);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        imageFactory.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                        resizedImage = await CreateAsync(new Images(ms) { Name = resizedName });
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        await callback(resizedImage);

    });

}
```

A minor re-factor... but no harm done.

Thanks for all your help!